# Unreadable word in latin 18. century church death record

Tags: palaeography, 18th-century, austria, church-records, latin

I'm unable to decrypt some word in a Latin church record of a death in 1769. It is available at [Matricula Online](http://data.matricula-online.eu/de/oesterreich/gurk/pusarnitz/P12_029-1/?pg=52) (the second last entry on the page). Since the image is licensed CC-BY-NC-ND 2.0 I cannot reproduce it in part here. Because of the NC I'm not even sure if I can reproduce it in full. So I'm sticking with the link.

I think the entry reads

```
Die 29 aprilis mortus est Antonius Schmölzer 
rusticus rite provisus causa mortis fuit hydrops
cum gfritot [?] humatus et tumba 1 May etatis fuo
69 annorum.
```

which I interpret as

> On April 29th provided with the last rites the farmer Anton Schmölzer died by cause of oedema with ?. He was buried in the grave on May 1st and was 69 years old.

I'm not even sure if the word is in Latin. Anybody recognising this word?

Comment: That might be capital H instead of a "gf"

Comment: Maybe 9 and h. When looking at "Oberherzog" in the entry just above the one I referenced I find it unlikely that both parts form only one letter.

Comment: Just possibly Phritophumatus - I do think it is a single word. But I can't find anything similar in medical dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, medical dictionary would be a good idea. What for me counts against the possibility that it is one word is that "humatus/humata" and "tumba" also occur in the other entries without the prefix of this entry.

Comment: Use Firefox and take a screenshot to get copy.

Answer (score 1):

"causa mortis fuit hydrops cum gfritok"

"Died by cause of dropsy (a now-obsolete term which defined the accumulation of fluid in the body) due to fried potatoes/fries [fritok]"

It was believed greasy, fatty foods, such as fried chicken, fried potatoes/fries, anything fried -- can make you feel bloated as they linger in your stomach. Indigestion results from eating high-fat foods (or just eating in excess overall).